# How to dynamically open files for writing with a with statement

Tags: python

I am trying to split out one large file into an unknown number of files based on a field on a row by row basis. In this case, I want all records with a July 2016 date to write to one file, August 2016 to another, etc. I don't want to have to comb through the file twice, first to populate a list of files that need to be created, and then to actually write to them.

My first thought was to create a dictionary where the key was the file name (based on the date) and the return was a class that would write out to the csv files.

```
import csv

class testClass:
    a = None
    k = None

    def __init__(self,theFile):
        with open(theFile,'wb') as self.k:
            self.a = csv.writer(self.k)


    def writeOut(self,inString):
        self.a.writerow(inString)

testDict = {'07m19':testClass('07m19_test2')}


testDict['07m19'].writeOut(['test'])
```

When i try to run this I get the following error:

`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Which makes sense, by the time the class is done initializing theFile is closed.

I think the with statement is required because the files are very big and I can't load it all into memory. That being said, I am not sure how else to approach this.

Comment: Just use a plain open. The ‘with’ closes the file.

Comment: Using a class is probably overkill for what you want to do.

Comment: So if I omit the with it won't impact memory usage at all?

Comment: No, it won't impact memory usage. If you insist on using a class here (which I don't recommend), then you may want to define a destructor `__del__(self)` that closes the file `self.k` when your class instance is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need a class for this. Let's pretend that your input file is a csv file and has the full name of the month in the first column:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for rownum,row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile),1):
        month = row[0]
        with open('path/to/output_{}.csv'.format(month), 'a') as outfile:
        if not rownum%100: print("Processed row", rownum, end='\r', flush=True)
            csv.writer(outfile).writerow(row)
    print("Processed row", rownum)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't load it all into memory

You are not loading it all to memory by [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)ing a file. You just create a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object). When you do `f.read()` you load all its contents to memory as a string.

So you can do:

```py
class testClass:
    def __init__(self,theFile):
        self.k = open(theFile,'wb')
        self.a = csv.writer(self.k)

    def writeOut(self,inString):
        self.a.writerow(inString)

    def __del__(self):
        self.k.close()
```

Because it is not guarenteed that `__del__` will be called at the end of execution you might want to add a `close` method and call it just like with files.

Answer (score -1):

```
 def __init__(self,theFile):
        self.k = open(theFile,'wb')
        self.a = csv.writer(self.k)
```

Comment: With `open` like this, you don't close the file at the end of the code.

Comment: Well, one problem at a time. The OP has a file which is not open at all.